# Error when creating a list of objects - NullPointerException

Tags: java, list, arraylist, nullpointerexception

This should be something fairly simple but I can't figure out my error. First up I am trying to write a program which will take user input and add the input as an object to a list called `aList`. I have two classes one called `Group` and one called `ListObject`.

Here is the `Group` class code

```
public class Group
{


 List<ListObject> aList = new ArrayList();
   public Group()
   {


   }

   public void addObject(Object aName)
   {
      aList.add(aName);     

   }
}
```

Here is my ListObject class

```
public class ListObject
{

    private String name;
    public int value;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public ListObject(String aName)
    {
       super();
       this.name = firstName;
       this.value = 10;            
    }
}
```

I need the method in the Group class to take user input, create an object of that name and then add it to the list `aList` and have all objects in that list be assigned as value of -1 to begin with. For some reason I am being returned a NullPopinterException. Hopefully you can point out what I've missed. Please note I did have this working when I was just adding strings instead of instances of the `ListObject` Objects.

Comment: Your `Group` class shouldn't even compile... you haven't got an `aList` field, only a local variable in the constructor. And if that *were* a field, then you wouldn't be able to call `add(Object)` on it, as it's a `List<ListObject>`, not a `List<Object>`... Please post a short but complete program showing the actual failure - after reading http://tinyurl.com/so-npe

Comment: Sorry that's probably an error with me transferring my code over to here as it is written slightly differently. I will append these errors

Comment: No, don't just "append these errors" - edit the code in the question to be a short but complete program which actually demonstrates the problem. But yes, you should include a stack trace too...

Comment: Besides being in the constructor, I don't think you can assign `ArrayList` to a `List` like that.

Comment: I have re-written it, and it does at least compile on my end

Comment: when I call the method addStudents() with the argument "Dave" for example I get the NullPointerException. Hopefully you can tell me where ive gone wrong

Comment: @JackB See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: Well, the `aList` field is never initialized - in the constructor you're declaring a *different* variable...

Comment: @JonSkeet i've now edited it to include Chetan Kinger's solution and it's throwing me a new error. Any ideas?

Comment: @JackB: Yes - you investigate it, and if you still can't fix it you post a new question. One question, one post - and with more details than "a new error".

Comment: You're also now claiming to get both a compile-time error *and* an exception...

Comment: @JonSkeet I've removed that part now. Question has been answered. if theres anything I need to clarify for other users let me know

Comment: Well the code that you've included in the question still wouldn't compile, rather than throwing a NullPointerException... please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as follows :

```
public class Group {
   List<ListObject> aList = new ArrayList();

   public Group() {
      super();
   }

   public void addObject(ListObject aName) {
      aList.add(aName);     
   }
}
```

There were two problems with your code :

1. The `aList` local variable that you re-defined within the constructor was hiding the the `aList` instance variable. You ended up intializing the local variable `aList` in the constructor instead of initializing the `aList` instance variable. Therefore, the instance variable was always be null and you got a `NullPointerException` when you called the `add` method in `addToList` on a null reference.
2. Your list is declared as `List<ListObject>`. This means that the list can only hold objects of type `ListObject`. This is known as `type-safety`. The argument  of the `addObject` method should be changed to `ListObject`. Also note that you need to create a `ListObject` and pass it to the `addObject` method.

Comment: The code the OP provided wouldn't even have compiled - there's no point in answering until the question actually makes *sense*, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed. Temporarily deleted and re-answered.

Comment: Thanks for this, there is one problem that the meethod requires two arguments (Object and Int). I assume the int is for the ListObject value but I need all of the objects to automatically assigned to -1, rather than having their values input by the method

Comment: @JackB You can't have a negative index position in an array.

Comment: Let me clarify: when trying to compile I get the error

`no suitable method found for add(java.lang.Object)`

Comment: @ChetanKinger what would be a suitable substitutefor the -1 ? I can't use any value between 1 and 100

Comment: @JackB Such an error is not possible from the limited code that you have posted. I suggest you post a new question that provides more details. Also, I believe I have answered your immediate question.

Comment: ok I'll try reposting what I have now

    `public void addObject(Object aName)
    {
        aList.add(aName);
    }`

gives the error `method java.util.List.add(int,ListObject) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)`

Comment: ^ i'll add that to the bottom of the original post so its more readable

Comment: @JackB I have edited the answer to resolve this error. If you get any more errors, please post a new question. The purpose of Stackoverflow is not to provide you with a personal instructor. Your questions should be helpful to other users as well.

Comment: @ChetanKinger thank you so much, that works great. Just has to change from List<ListObject> to List<Object> as you said. Thanks for sticking at it, I know I didn't make it easy for you

Comment: @ChetanKinger Yes, of course. I now need to be able to access the values of the objects (which in this case should be -1). At the moment I am unsure whether I am adding Objects or Strings to aList

Comment: @ChetanKinger For example when I try to print out the added objects I will need it to print out the names and their values